# Elasticsearch xpack RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS_mgf1:first octet invalid

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, openssl, azure-keyvault, pem

- AKS: 1.20.7
- Elasticsearch : 7.12.0
- client: openssl

**Description of the problem**

- Cluster fails to come live when PEM files are downloaded from cloud and mounted @ /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs without a custom Elasticsearch image
- Works fine with a custom Elasticsearch image and PEM files copied to /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs during image building
- PEM files are downloaded from KeyVault using CSI driver

**PEM files downloaded from cloud provider (Error case)**

```
[elasticsearch@test-rp-search-master-0 ~]$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:9200
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
140680078673728:error:0407E086:rsa routines:RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS_mgf1:last octet 
invalid:crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.c:88:
140680078673728:error:1417B07B:SSL routines:tls_process_cert_verify:bad 
signature:ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:505:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
   i:C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = Research Platform Issuing CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEzDCCArSgAwIBAgIUIQThqQtH1QPR3YocBxLrrj+RQ9owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwVzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgMAlVTMRQwEgYDVQQKDAtTZWxmIFNp
```

**PEM files in the Elasticsearch custom images (Works fine)**

```
[elasticsearch@test-rp-search-master-0 ~]$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:9200
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = test-rp-search-data
   i:C = US, ST = US, O = Self Signed, CN = Research Platform Issuing CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEzDCCArSgAwIBAgIUIQThqQtH1QPR3YocBxLrrj+RQ9YwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwVzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgMAlVTMRQwEgYDVQQKDAtTZWxmIFNp
```